# How react container runs vuejs code in micro frontends architecture

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, micro-frontend

### summarize

**vue js code not running in container app**

> to be specific, the main.js code in vue js is not running...

### description

i am currently developing MFA (Micro Frontends Architecture) with reference [here](https://github.com/rehrumesh/react-microfrontend-container).

architecture configuration is as follows.

1. container app(react):

> container apps have common components such as header and footer.
> request asset-manifest.json from the remote app. and load the built js into the script. then, execute the render function of each app.

2. react app (remote app)

> micro frontend

3. vue app (remote app)

> micro frontend

**to explain the operation process,** each app declares a render function on the window object. afterwards, the container app receives the *asset-manifest.json* from the app that needs it, receives the built-in js file, and executes the render function declared above.

### So what's the problem?

react works fine, but in case of vue, there is no render function declared in the window object.

### code

***container app***

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';

function MicroFrontend({ name, host, history }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const scriptId = `micro-frontend-script-${name}`;

    const renderMicroFrontend = () => {
      window[`render${name}`](`${name}-container`, history);
    };

    if (document.getElementById(scriptId)) {
      renderMicroFrontend();
      return;
    }

    fetch(`${host}/asset-manifest.json`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((manifest) => {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.id = scriptId;
        script.crossOrigin = '';
        script.src = `${host}${manifest.files['main.js']}`;
        script.onload = () => {
          renderMicroFrontend();
        };
        document.head.appendChild(script);
      });

    return () => {
      window[`unmount${name}`] && window[`unmount${name}`](`${name}-container`);
    };
  });

  return <main id={`${name}-container`} />;
}

MicroFrontend.defaultProps = {
  document,
  window,
};

export default MicroFrontend;
```

***react app***
almost identical to the vue project.

***vue app***

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import store from './store';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

window.renderVueApp = (containerId) => {
  new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    render: (h) => h(App),
  }).$mount(containerId);
};

window.unmountVueApp = (containerId) => {
  const root = document.getElementById(containerId);

  if (root) {
    root.remove();
  }
};

if (!document.getElementById('VueApp-container')) {
  new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    render: (h) => h(App),
  }).$mount('#root');
}
```

***vue.config.js***

```js
const WebpackAssetsManifest = require('webpack-assets-manifest');

const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service');
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  configureWebpack: (config) => {
    config.entry = './src/main.js';
    config.plugins = config.plugins.concat(
      new WebpackAssetsManifest({
        output: 'asset-manifest.json',
        customize(entry) {
          return {
            key: `${entry.key.replace('app', 'main')}`,
            value: `/${entry.value}`,
          };
        },
        transform(assets) {
          return {
            files: assets,
          };
        },
      }),
    );
  },
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.merge({
      externals:
        process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
          ? []
          : {
              vue: 'Vue',
              'vue-router': 'VueRouter',
            },
    });
  },
});
```

it's so hard because i can't find a way....
any help would be appreciated.